# TypeScript call static function from other module

Tags: javascript, typescript

I got a problem when i want to create global function in another module

utils.ts file (contain global function)

```
/// <reference path="jquery/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="knockout/index.d.ts" />
'use strict';

module com.test.project {
    export class utils {
        self: any;

        constructor() {
            this.self = this;
        }

        public postData(url: string, data: any): any {
            var dfd = $.Deferred();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                type: 'post',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    return dfd.done(result);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    return dfd.reject(result);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

login.ts (call global function inside)

```
/// <reference path="jquery/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="knockout/index.d.ts" />
'use strict';

module com.test.project.login {
    export class ScreenModel {
        self: any;
        userName: KnockoutObservable<string>;
        password: KnockoutObservable<string>;

        constructor() {
            this.self = this;
            this.userName = ko.observable("") as KnockoutObservable<string>;
            this.password = ko.observable("") as KnockoutObservable<string>;
        }

        private submit(): void {
            var dataObject = {
                "userName": this.userName(),
                "password": this.password()
            }
            // ↓ error here
            com.test.project.utils.postData("loginService.do", dataObject).done(function(result) {
                window.location.href = "index.do";
            }).reject(function(result) {
                alert("error");
            });
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
       ko.applyBindings(new ScreenModel()); 
    });
}
```

The global function inside module com.test.project and in class utils, normally, the global function caller inside module like com.test.project.[function] and in class ScreenModel.
How can i call the global function inside ScreenModel class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're thinking too much in a Java Style: I'd recommend you to declare in the `utils` module an object with a function called `postData` and import just that object in your login module.

Something like this:

```
export const utils = {
  postData(url, data) {
    $.ajax({})
  }
}

// ....

import { utils } from './utils'
utils.postData(url, data)
...
```

OR

export just your `util` function

```
export function postData(....)

import { postData } from './utils'
postData()
```

Comment: I tried both, but still got error `Import declarations in a namespace cannot reference a module.` in login.ts file

Comment: Remove all module stuff

Comment: I tried but still error, any other ideal? [My current code](http://i.imgur.com/ATOQdzV.png)

Comment: oh... i had resolved, the problem is - put import statement inside module :D

Answer (score 0):

You already have it in your question's title: You must declare it as `static`, e.g. `public static postData`. There is a huge difference in the resulting JavaScript, see [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20bar()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20bar()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%202%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Without static, the function is assigned to the prototype, hence you need an instance of that class to call the function.

Comment: tried add static keyword but i still got an error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postData' of undefined`